# Multiple Dovecot single IMAP sign in

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

May be my query is too feezy to understand. But i'll try to explain what i want.

**I have 2 dovecot servers**

- 1st emample1.com is hosted with server1.dataserver.com where example1.com users has their emails
- 2nd example2.com is hosted with server2.dataserver.com where example2.com users has their emails

I want to keep single imap.server.com as single sign in platform where my both server users can verify their accounts for mobile and desktop.

What can be done in this case? LDAP, Z-Push, Can use Postfix SASL Authentication for multiple dovecot?

Outgoing is not an issue i can route smtp connections via multiple SMTP servers but i want solution for multi dovecot server with single sign in IMAP setup.

Regards

Comment: What do you want to run on `imap.example.com` (use [RFC 2606](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) domain names in your question or your own): an IMAP server or a WebMail interface?

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz Thans for letting me know, edited my question. I can use Rainloop if i want to webmail and can connect many more user data servers OR make own php imap connection server. 

I want user from both servers will use same imap server as incoming mail server and same SMTP serever for outgoing mails. 

Just like we do with gsuite.

Comment: Basically, you are looking for some version of [Dovecot clustering](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/dovecot_cluster_architecture/)

Answer (score 0):

After wasting so much time, i have found the solution for allowing access to all user mailbox server to connect via single Server Authentication e.g. imap.myserver.com.

Users can access webmail or mobile setups or desktop setups via single phase authentication to dovecot mapped by postfix alias & using IMAP Proxy Server by Dovecot.

https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/proxies/

You should carefully consider these lines in your `dovecot.conf` file

```
# Space separated list of trusted network ranges. Connections from these
# IPs are allowed to override their IP addresses and ports (for logging and
# for authentication checks). disable_plaintext_auth is also ignored for
# these networks. Typically you'd specify your IMAP proxy servers here.
login_trusted_networks =
```

Article on this page helps me to figure it out the things, this article shows how we can do that using password file but i'm going to use hash password db file for this

https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=2077